# how to get distinct count of values from a column which has string array values(comma separated data) when using Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a postgresql database table which has a column which stores selected candidate ids in **string arrays** ,according to the roles.
eg:

```
{id:1,selectedCandidates:[11d,3c,4f]}
{id:2,selectedCandidates:[141d,34c,4f]}
{id:3,selectedCandidates:[3c]}
```

The selectedCandidate ids are saved as comma separated data in string array format .so I need to calculate the **total number of selected distinct candidates**.(total number of distinct selectedCandidate ids in SelectedCandidates column)

Comment: Why are you storing the ID and and the candidates in a single column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are storing the data in a table like this:

```
create table candidates (
   id integer,
   selectedcandidates _text
);
```

and some data:

```
 insert into candidates
  values
  (1, '{11d,3c,4f}'::text[]),
  (2, '{141d,34c,4f}'::text[]),
  (3, '{3c}'::text[]);
```

You can count candidate occurrances like this:

```
select candidate_id, count(candidate_id) 
  from candidates,
  lateral (select * from unnest(selectedcandidates)) cand(candidate_id)
 group by candidate_id;
```

Best regards,
Bjarni